# Intelligent jar exlusion in exported jar/apk possible?

Tags: java, android, compilation

Quick question relating android, but probably that touches java programming in general (would be great if that is possible with eclipse/java platform).

Lets say I have an external library, which I add to my application. (Android Library added to Android Application Project, from android perspective). Now if I commit from using any class, or whatever it is, at all from that library project inside my main application project, will the output jar/apk file contain the library jar file nevertheless, or won't?

Follow up question to that above (simpler case). Lets say I have library project like above (lets call it MainLibrary), which I DO use in some extend in my main project. Now this library, has other library project/jar referenced (lets say LinkedinLibrary) which it uses internaly. So the calls within the MainLibrary use LinkedinLibrary to some extend.

Now, like I pointed out my main application do use the MainLibrary, but doesn't use anything at all from MainLibrary, which internaly uses LinkedinLibrary.

With my application, MainLibrary jar is there in the output obviously. What about LinkedinLibrary jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now if I ommit from using any class, or whatever it is, at all from that library project inside my main application project, will the output jar/apk file contain the library jar file nevertheless, or won't?

If you put the JAR in the libs folder it will.

> Follow up question to that above (simpler case). Lets say I have library project like above (lets call it MainLibrary), which I DO use in some extend in my main project. Now this library, has other library project/jar referenced (lets say LinkedinLibrary) which it uses internaly.

That depends on your project structure. For example: If you just put the JAR of your MainLibrary in the libs folder, the linked projects will be missing. But if you have all projects in your Eclipse workspace and added the projects via properties dialog AND configured it to export the linked libraries too, it will work.

That's all what the basic Eclipse build system is delivering. If you're fiddling around with Gradle dependencies it works out of the box - if you get this buggy piece of Android Studio to work. It also works out of the box if you're using Maven, which seems to be way more stable than Gradle in Android Studio at the moment.

Generally speaking it depends on your build system.

- Maven works out of the box.
- Gradle too.
- If you're using ant, you need to write it yourself or use some custom tasks like the [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) or the Maven dependency plugin.

Edit:/
You also asked if it would be possible. I know no dependency management system which works by source code inspection. So if you don't need an existing dependency you have to remove it yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick resonse. In refference to your first statement, if my library from first example, was added by project, not with a library jar, then the main application would not contain library's jar, but if I put jar in the libs folder explicitely, it would? Did I understand you correctly? I'm asking, because your "edit remark" seems to contradict the above.

Comment: If you put your JAR in the libs folder it's added to the APK. The build system doesn't care if you use classes from the JARs or don't. It just puts them in.

Comment: Yes, that's very clear. But I was asking about the other situation, if I add library not by jar refference, but by project refference. So for example I have in my workspace 2 projects. My main project, and library project. If I add library project by refference to my main project, but my main project will not use anything from library project, will it contain library's jar nevertheless?

Comment: Yes it will. As said above: The build system or the dependency management system doesn't scan your code to determine if you actually used a class or not. 
You could write something like that yourself, but why keep the not used JAR in the folder in the first place?

Comment: Thanks a lot schlingel, I appriciate it.
(I was considering making a one big library for myself, which would include a lot of stuff in it, instead of breaking all those tools into sepparate libraries)